# How to display progressbar in android while loading the data from remote database?

Tags: android, progress-bar

How to display progressbar i'm calling intent from class A to class B.
In which class B lloads the data from the using parsing mean while
this happens i'm getting blank screen in this time i'd like to show
progressbar how can i do that.

Right now i'm writing the code as follows..

```
class A extends Activity{
    oncreate(){ 
        ...
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new performBackgroundtask().execute(); 
        } 
    } 

    class performBackgroundtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        //
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this,"", "Please wait...");                  
            super.onPreExecute();

            /*
             * progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading ...");
             * progressDialog.show(); progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
             */         
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Intent in = new Intent(A.this, B.class);                    
            startActivity(in);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();       
        }
    } 
}

class B { ...
/*
 * In which this class has another view which has to get the data from
 * URL using SAXPArsing.
 *
 * ... for this where i need to write progress bar code.
 */
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in doInBackground(Void... params) method of AsyncTask?

Comment: Intent which calls another class in which it needs to load the data from server.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using a handler. When the handler recieves it's response from a thread, you can dismiss your progressdialog.

Some code to help you understand:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage( Message message )
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            // My irrelevant code here
        }
    };

    new Thread( new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Do your stuff here
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage( 1, text );
            handler.sendMessage( message );
        }
      }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling another Activity class to do your downloading, move this functionality into another class that each Activity can use.